# How can I use CMD to find out to which WiFi network i am connected?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I am in need to find out via the command line to what WiFi network I am connected, is there a command to find out?

Comment: Is it not possible to simply look in the network and sharing centre, or even hovering over the WiFi icon in the taskbar?

Answer (score 13):

This will show the profiles the current profile is the connection

```
Netsh wlan show profiles
```

Other example: SSID is the current connected wifi.

```
Netsh WLAN show interfaces
```

Comment: On my Windows 10, `show profiles` just shows the saved network profiles and `show interfaces` provides the active profile. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
netsh wlan show profiles
```

The one you are using right now is **Current User Profile**.

Comment: "Current User Profile" doesn't appear on my Windows 10. And yes, I'm connected.